# How to use same IDs for players across multiple apps with Facebook's new Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am in the process of upgrading my apps to Graph API v2.0.

It seems that I cannot use Facebook universal IDs anymore. But the issue is that I have multiple games and users can play them all with the same account, so they can have their balance and level across all games.

I am worried about the new API as it seems that this will not be possible anymore. Is there any way to do this without the Facebook ID?

Comment: Use the business mapping api to map id between apps

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Business Mapping API at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business

For convenience, probably the best option would be to use the `token_for_business` field in the User object.

Comment: Hi Tobi, Thank you for your answer. 

Unfortunately, that does not solve my issue as this can only allow me to know whether or not a specific user has played my other games but it does not provide a way to share his account across multiple games. 

That’s what I’m looking for. 
Thanks

Comment: Sharing the user_id across Apps is not possible. But you can map the different ids via the Business Mapping API. That's what it's for.